# .on() jQuery function not working after page updated via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code essentially shows hidden content and reassigns a new button when it does the function.

The problem I am having is that when pagination is selected, or the price slider is selected/used, the function is not readied again.

My jQuery .on() code works fine in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/Fgx7D/4/) but not in the test environment (http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/uk/offers/icat/7offers):

**HTML:**

```
<img class="brands-toggle" id="#brandresults" src="http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/+.png">
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(".brands-toggle").bind( "click", function() {
    var collapse_content_selector = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var toggle_switch = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).css('display') == 'none') {
            toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/-.png","http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/+.png"));
        } else {
            toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/+.png", "http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/-.png"));
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Changed the syntax to work with earlier version of jQuery - use of .bind() instead of .on().

Still the problem with it not reloading after AJAX call.

Comment: Your _search.js_ file is having an issue with `.on()`

Comment: If you check your browser's console log you'll see the problem: `[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery(document).on') global code (Search.js, line 300)`. This is happening because you're using jQuery v1.6.1 and `.on()` was only added in 1.7.

Comment: um, your toggle() code looks wrong....shouldn't it be returning a boolean?

Comment: just a hint on the side: replace("http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/-.png","http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/+.png")) could be written: replace("-.png","+.png"))

Comment: Ah, I see folks... perhaps .bind() is the way forward then?

Comment: @HarryL - it's advised to use [`.delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in jQuery versions below 1.7 for this kind of event delegation.

Comment: @joe - that's all in now and the animation is working. I'll have to wrap this with a function that will check for the correct ajax calls to the server and have it display correctly because at the moment it's still misbehaving.

Comment: @HarryL - it's not working properly right now because `#col-one` is being replaced when an option is selected. Trying using a different selector like `.wpShadow` (just an example). Also, your ajax request isn't replacing `#content-search` it's just adding it inside the current one meaning you end up with multiple `#content-search` elements on the page.

Comment: @Joe, that's only gone and bloody done it! Now to have the content drop stay open when returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was cleared up and .delegate() was a more appropriate method:

**jQuery:**

```
    // 1.1 Brands toggle

jQuery(".wpShadow").delegate( ".boxContent #brand", "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var collapse_content_selector = jQuery('#brandresults');
    var toggle_switch = jQuery(this).find('img');
        if (jQuery(collapse_content_selector).css('display') == 'none') {
            toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("bkg-dropdown.png","bkg-dropdown-minus.png"));
        } else {
            toggle_switch.attr("src", toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("bkg-dropdown-minus.png", "bkg-dropdown.png"));
        }   
    jQuery(collapse_content_selector).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$('body').on` instead of `$(document)/on`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RahilWazir in the test environment it does say `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`